# Meteor: MailChimp Subscription

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to build a newsletter subscription for MailChimp on my meteor site. I think I've done everything that the doc says, but when I click on the submit button, simply nothing happens. Why?

This is in my html:

```
<template name="MailChimpListSubscribe"> 
    <section class="mailchimp">
        <div class="row">
             <form id="subscribe-footer" class="form-inline">
                <input class="mailchimp-email form-control" type="email" placeholder="ADDRESS@EMAIL.COM" />
                <button class="mailchimp-subscribe btn btn-success"  type="button">SUBMIT</button>
                <div class="message signup"><p>Sign up for our newsletter</p></div>
                <label class="error-message"></label>
                {{#if message}}
                <div class="mailchimp-message message thankyou"><p>You will now receive emails from us</p></div>
                {{/if}}
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

in server/settings.json:

```
{
    "private": {
        "MailChimp": {
            "apiKey": "myapikey",
            "listId": "listid"
        }
    }
}
```

in clien/js/mailchimplistsubscribe.js

```
Template.MailChimpListSubscribe.onRendered (function (){
    jQuery(".message.signup").mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass('disappear');
    })

  var template = this;

  $( "#subscribe-footer" ).validate({
    rules: {
      emailAddress: {
        email: true,
        required : true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      emailAddress: {
        email: "Please use a valid email address!",
        required: "An email address is required."
      }
    },
    errorPlacement: function( error, element ) {
      $( ".error-message" ).text( error[0].innerText );
    },
    success: function( error ) {
      $( ".error-message" ).text( error[0].innerText );
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
      handleSubscriber({
        email: template.find( "[name='emailAddress']" ).value,
        action: 'subscribe'
      });
    }
  });


});
```

console error:

```
handleSubscriber is not defined
```

Comment: can you please paste your javascript code you are using for the api call?

Comment: try handleSubscriber:function(){email: .....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you verify the following:

- You did install the package `meteor add miro:mailchimp` with no errors
- You don't have any error msgs on the console
- You have a valid account at *mailchimp*
- You put in the correct `apiKey` and `listId`

Beside this,
try to **change** the way you are working with external settings... (your `settings.js`)
You have to create a file name `settings.json` (and not `.js`)
in your root project folder (and not in your `server` folder)
Inside this file you should put the code you entered at your `server/settings.js`
then you have to start your meteor application with the command:
`meteor --settings=settings.json`

---

**-- EDIT --** (After you change the question ;) )

1. I guess that you are trying to follow the tutorial at: https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/mailing-lists-with-mailchimp/
2. In this tutorial, they create the helper function `handleSubscriber` in the file `/client/modules/handle-subscriber.js`
   Please make sure you have it in your project
3. All the project code is available at: https://github.com/themeteorchef/mailing-lists-with-mailchimp, you can download it, play with it and then integrate it into your project.
   there is a demo of this project from the same URL

the code you are missing (Coping it from the-meteor-chef link I mentioned before)

```
handleSubscriber = function( subscriber ) {
     Meteor.call( "handleSubscriber", subscriber, function( error, response ) {
         // Handle error or response here.
     });
};
```

Please verify that you have all the packages they install for the project as well

From the project on GitHub, in the `.meteor` folder, there is a file named `packages` that contain the list of all the packages that the project is using.
This is the content of that file: (You have to verify that each package is installed!)

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.
standard-app-packages
underscore
accounts-password
accounts-base
jquery
check
audit-argument-checks
iron:router
themeteorchef:jquery-validation
twbs:bootstrap
meteorhacks:npm
npm-container
themeteorchef:bert
meteorhacks:ssr
fourseven:scss
miro:mailchimp
browser-policy
reactive-var
fortawesome:fontawesome
```

Comment: 1) I did install the package. I see it in the package file. 2) console says TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function. 3) I have a valid account at mailchimp. 4) correct info the apiKey and listID 4) settings.json is correct - I had a typo in my post, I also have the same file in the root, and I started the app with the command

Comment: I discovered I didn't have jqueryvalidate plugin. Now I added and the console is now giving handleSubscriber is not defined error

Comment: Based on this new information and on the changes you made in your question, I added to my answer.   Hope it will solve your issue now